# Storing input data in JS class

Tags: javascript, forms, class, oop, input

my little project is for user to fill out 2 forms. When you submit the first one, second one will apear. When you submit a second form, it will re-direct you to another page where all data will be displayed. I managed to get data from second form using PHP, but I've been told, that I need to store inputs into JS class and then display it...

Form 1:

```
<fieldset>
     <legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
     <p>
         <label for="firstname">First name</label>
         <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
         <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
     </p>
     <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email</label>
         <input id="confirm_email" name="confirm_email" type="email">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="agree">Please agree to our policy</label>
         <input id="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="agree" type="checkbox">
     </p>
 </fieldset>
```

This is my code for showing/ hiding forms:

```
  $( "#signupForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
     $( "#signupForm2" ).show( "slow" );


     $( "#signupForm" ).hide( "fast" );
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

And all I came up with JS classes is this:

```
 class store_data{
        constructor(){
            this.firstname = ['firstname'];
            this.lastname = ['lastname']
        }
 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: so what is the problem here? Should you rewrite the class?

Comment: My problem is, I have no idea how to store that data into class and then display it. I've watched some tutorials on JS class but I don't know how to use it in this case...

Comment: in previous versions of Javascript, there is no such thing as classes. Yet, the concept of classes could be implemented in various ways.

Comment: Have a look to this tutorial https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/javascript-classes-under-the-hood-6b26d2667677

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( "#signupForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $( "#signupForm2" ).show( "slow" );
     $( "#signupForm" ).hide( "fast" );
     const firstname = $("#firstname").val();
     const lastname = $("#lastname").val();

     const person = new Person(firstname, lastname)
     person.greet()
    
 });
 
 class Person {
 
        constructor(firstname, lastname){
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname
        }
        
        greet() {
        console.log(`He, I'm ${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`)
        }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signupForm">
<fieldset>
     <legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
     <p>
         <label for="firstname">First name</label>
         <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
         <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
     </p>
     <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email</label>
         <input id="confirm_email" name="confirm_email" type="email">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="agree">Please agree to our policy</label>
         <input id="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="agree" type="checkbox">
     </p>
     <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But I get "Hey, I'm undefinedundefined" in console after submit

Comment: I edited it 4-5 minutes ago which one did you run? Now I get `He, I'm fsd dsf` which is correct :) just run the snippet right here